# Local directory autoload - "Class not found"

Tags: composer-php, vagrant, psr-4

I've got a mind-bender here that I must be missing something. I have a `web` directory, with two libraries as sibling directories:

```
/
  web/
    vendor/
      composer/
        autoload_psr4.php
        ...
      autoload.php
    index.php
  lib-one/
    src/
      A.php
  lib-two/
    src/
      B.php
```

The class files:

#### A.php

```
<?php

namespace Org\LibOne;

class A
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}
```

#### B.php

```
<?php

namespace Org\LibTwo;

class B
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}
```

I've run `composer update`, which generates the expected `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` file:

#### vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Org\\LibOne\\' => array($baseDir . '/../lib-one/src'),
    'Org\\LibTwo\\' => array($baseDir . '/../lib-two/src'),
);
```

Finally, inside the web directory I have an index file with the following code:

#### index.php

```
<?php

include('vendor/autoload.php');

use Org\LibOne\A;
use Org\LibTwo\B;

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
```

`$a` is assigned an instance of `A` just fine, while `$b` errors, saying `Class 'Org\LibTwo\B' not found in 'web/index.php line 9'`.

The **only** difference is I added `Org\LibTwo` after the code utilizing `Org\LibOne` was already functioning.

I have quintuple-checked spelling, namespacing, directories etc. Please help return my sanity.

Comment: Is is actually reproducible on this `A` and `B` example? This may be related to class names (like case-sensitivity), providing original names may be crucial here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! And of course, it was an easy, but often overlooked solution. In our case, we use the vagrant development box [rlerdorf/php7dev](https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev). The file `php7dev.yaml` contains directory mappings, to which I forgot to add `lib-two`, and was too focused on Composer being the source of the problem.